# Comparing the two feature sets

Tags: dataset, data, experiments

I am working on a classification of two feature sets derived from a dataset. We first obtain two feature matrices derived from two feature extraction methods. Now, I need to compare them. However, the recognition accuracy for two feature sets, reaches almost the same recognition accuracy. My question is:

- Is there a way to design a meaningful experiment to show the difference between the two methods? What are your suggestions?

Comment: Please add the explanation and example in your question. I deleted the answer since it was completely irrelevant after you edit to question.

Comment: May be you are looking for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108399/machine-learning-how-to-compare-different-feature-sets

Comment: Sorry. I just edited.

Comment: Actually, I did 10-fold cross validation by SVM. The result for both, close to each other.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by example. I need a method to have a meaningful comparison between two feature sets?

Comment: It actually depends on why you need this feature (I guess classification). Features in itself are some representation of data, which help us understand the data better. one way to compare them is to actually use a classification algorithm on both of them and measure the accuracy which you did. so if both have the same quality its the matter of dimensionality. the smaller one is because of abvious reasons better.